# Difficulties splitting long string of numbers in Python

Tags: python, string, split

I want to extract the list of the first 100,000 primes from a Gutemberg textfile, but the string `primes` produced from that file doesn't respond to `.split()` as expected.

I tried printing the separator character from one line to the next, it's a blank space, and its `ord` is 13, which seems to be related to vertical tabs.

```py
import requests

url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/65/65.txt"

long_primes_string = requests.get(url).content

# beginning: 1788
# end: -19130
primes = long_primes_string[1788:-19130]

print primes[1]
print ord(primes[1])

primes.split(primes[1])
print primes[:10]
```

I was expencting a list of strings of the primes from 2 to the 100,000th prime, but the `split` function seemingly does nothing. I also tried invoking `primes.split()` without an argument, again, nothing happens.

Comment: `split` returns a list of strings, and does not change `primes`.

Comment: If i unterstand it correctly, you should split by new line like \n and not by whitespace example mystring.split('\n')

Comment: @Daniel ... indeed :P thank you for your comment, that solves it.

Comment: @Daniel Please add a short answer so I can close this question and feel less embarassed ^^

Comment: As an aside, Python 2.x will be EOL'd [very soon](https://pythonclock.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it's a blank space, and its ord is 13, which seems to be related to vertical tabs.

It's a newline. In practice, vertical tabs are extremely rare.

> primes.split(primes[1])

This creates a **new** list of strings, each of which is a line from the original text, and then **throws it away**. You need to give this result a separate name (or re-use the existing `primes` name), and then use that result. For example:

```
prime_text = long_primes_string[1788:-19130]
primes = prime_text.split()
```

Comment: This will not work because it will generate an array with a single item (the entire `prime_test`)

Comment: Did you try it? `.split()` splits on any whitespace.

Comment: Yes I did. It could be that it's os specific and `\r\n` are recognized as whitespaces on windows but not on mac.

Answer (score 1):

We get the primes as a string '2\r\n3\r\n...' and should split accordingly, try:

```
primes = long_primes_string[1788:-19130]
primes = str(primes).split('\\r\\n')
```

The beginning and end might require additional handling but other than that you'll get all the numbers (as strings, you'll need to convert them to numbers if you want to use them as such).